# Issue in doInBackground process

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Getting problem when calling the class. I didn't get solution for my exact problem. Till my work is:

**Task.java:**

```
public class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
    Context context;
    FragmentActivity currentActivity;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    public Task(FragmentActivity activity)
    {
        currentActivity = activity;
        context=Constant.getContext();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        dialog=ProgressDialog.show(currentActivity, "Please wait...", "Loading..."); 

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
{
    ActivityWeatherSetting hh = new ActivityWeatherSetting();
    hh.initialize();
    return "success";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String params)
{
    //asyncclass.dismissProgressDialog();
    dialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

**AsyncClass.java:**

```
public abstract class AsyncClass extends Activity
{
    protected static final String TAG = AsyncClass.class.getSimpleName();


public ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private boolean destroyed = false;

Context context;

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    destroyed = true;
}

public void showLoadingProgressDialog()
{
    context=Constant.getContext();
    this.showProgressDialog("Loading. Please wait...");
    Log.d("this",this.toString());
}


public void showProgressDialog(CharSequence message)
{
    if (progressDialog == null)
    {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    progressDialog.setMessage(message);
    progressDialog.show();
}

public void dismissProgressDialog()
{
    if (progressDialog != null && !destroyed)
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

**ActivityWeatherSetting.java:**

```
public void initialize()
    {
        LayoutInflater layout = new LayoutInflater(Constant.getContext()) {


        @Override
        public LayoutInflater cloneInContext(Context newContext) {
            return null;
        }
    };
    view=(View)layout.inflate(R.layout.activity_grid_layout, null);
    boolean bResult = initializeData();

    if (bResult != false ){
        bResult = initializeView();
    }

    if (bResult == false){
        Log.e(TAG,"Init data failed");
        return;
    }
        drawWeatherScreen();
}    

private void updateDataOfCurrentLocation(){
    requestUpdateWeather();
}
private void requestUpdateWeather(){
    Message msgFetchData = new Message();
    msgFetchData.what = REG_GET_WEATHER_START;
    m_HandleRequest.sendMessage(msgFetchData);      
}



private void initializeHandleRequest(){
    m_Runnable = new Runnable(){

        //@Override
        public void run() {
            requestUpdateWeather();
        }           
    };
    /* Setting up handler for ProgressBar */
    m_HandleRequest = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            int nRequest = message.what;

            switch(nRequest){
            case REG_GET_WEATHER_START:
                String strWOEID = m_Preferneces.getLocation();
                if (strWOEID == null){
                    Log.e(TAG,"Can not get WOEID");
                    //m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    //displayNotifyCation(R.string.strFetchFailed);
                    return;
                } else {
                     //Get weather information 
                    m_WeatherInfo = m_DataModel.getWeatherData(strWOEID);           
                }

                Message msgRegSearch = new Message();
                msgRegSearch.what = REG_GET_WEATHER_FINISH;
                sendMessage(msgRegSearch);
                break;

            case REG_GET_WEATHER_FINISH:
                if (m_WeatherInfo != null){
                    updateWeatherInfo(m_WeatherInfo);
                    //notifyUpdateTime();
                }                   
                //m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();
                m_HandleRequest.postDelayed(m_Runnable, (ONE_MINUTE*m_Preferneces.getTimeUpdate()));
                break;

                 default:
                     Log.e(TAG,"Can not handle this message");
                     break;
            }
        }
    };      
}    



private boolean initializeView(){
    m_TextLocation = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.weatherset_location_txtview);
    m_Temperature = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.weatherset_temp_txtview);
    m_Humimidy = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.weatherset_humidity_txtview);
    m_Visibility = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.weatherset_visibility_txtview);
    m_WeatherIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.weather_icon);
    m_Date = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.dateTime);

    if ((m_TextLocation == null) || (m_Temperature == null) || 
            (m_Humimidy == null) || (m_WeatherIcon == null) ||
            (m_Visibility == null) || (m_Date == null)){
        Log.e(TAG,"View init failed");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private boolean initializeData(){
    /* Get application context */
    Context appContext = view.getContext();

    /* Get preference instance */
    m_Preferneces = WeatherPreferences.getInstance(appContext);
    if (m_Preferneces == null){
        Log.e(TAG, "Get preference instance failed, check please");
        return false;
    }

    /* Get instance of data model */
    m_DataModel = WeatherDataModel.getInstance();
    if (m_DataModel == null){
        Log.e(TAG,"Can not get data model");
        return false;
    }

    initializeHandleRequest();

    return true;
}    
private void drawWeatherScreen(){
    /
    updateDataOfCurrentLocation();
}
private void updateWeatherInfo(WeatherInfo weatherInfo)
{
    try
    {
    if (weatherInfo == null){
        Log.e(TAG,"Weather is null");
        return;
    }

    String strCode = weatherInfo.getCode();
    int nCode = getImageByCode(strCode);
    m_WeatherIcon.setImageResource(nCode);

    boolean bIsC = m_Preferneces.getTempFmt();

    String strFmt;
    String strTemp = weatherInfo.getTemperature(WeatherInfo.TEMPERATURE_FMT_CELSIUS);
    if (bIsC == true){
        strFmt = view.getContext().getString(R.string.str_temperature_fmt); 
    } else {
        strFmt = view.getContext().getString(R.string.str_temperature_fmt_f);
        strTemp = WeatherDataModel.convertC2F(strTemp);
    }

    //String strTemperature = String.format(strFmt, strTemp);
    strTemperature = String.format(strFmt, strTemp);

    m_TextLocation.setText(weatherInfo.getCity());
    m_Temperature.setText(strTemperature);
    m_Date.setText(weatherInfo.getDate());

    TextView humidity=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.humidityValue);
    TextView visibility=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.visiValue);
    strFmt = view.getContext().getString(R.string.str_humidity_fmt);
    String strHumidity = String.format(strFmt, weatherInfo.getHumidity());
    //m_Humimidy.setText(strHumidity);
    humidity.setText(strHumidity);
    strFmt = view.getContext().getString(R.string.str_visi_fmt);
    String strVisi = String.format(strFmt, weatherInfo.getVisibility());
    //m_Visibility.setText(strVisi);
    visibility.setText(strVisi);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Toast.makeText(ActivityWeatherSetting.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
private int getImageByCode(String strCode){
    int nImageCode = R.drawable.a0;

    if (strCode == null){
        Log.e(TAG,"Code is null");
        return nImageCode;
    }

    int nCode = Integer.parseInt(strCode);

    int nNumber= YahooWeatherHelper.m_ImageArr.length;
    for (int i=0; i < nNumber; i++){
        if (nCode == YahooWeatherHelper.m_ImageArr[i][1]){
            return YahooWeatherHelper.m_ImageArr[i][0];
        }
    }
    return nImageCode;
}
```

**Exception in LogCat:**

```
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.net.elderlyhealth.weather.ActivityWeatherSetting$3.<init>(ActivityWeatherSetting.java:384)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.net.elderlyhealth.weather.ActivityWeatherSetting.initializeHandleRequest(ActivityWeatherSetting.java:384)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.net.elderlyhealth.weather.ActivityWeatherSetting.initializeData(ActivityWeatherSetting.java:561)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.net.elderlyhealth.weather.ActivityWeatherSetting.initialize(ActivityWeatherSetting.java:137)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.net.elderlyhealth.weather.Task.doInBackground(Task.java:44)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at com.net.elderlyhealth.weather.Task.doInBackground(Task.java:1)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-18 13:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(585):  ... 5 more
11-18 13:38:23.420: I/dalvikvm(585): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 13:38:23.561: I/dalvikvm(585): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 13:38:23.920: I/dalvikvm(585): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
11-18 13:38:24.032: I/dalvikvm(585): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585): Activity com.net.elderlyhealth.view.ViewPagerFragmentActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4149f628 that was originally added here
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.net.elderlyhealth.view.ViewPagerFragmentActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4149f628 that was originally added here
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:116)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:99)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:94)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at com.net.elderlyhealth.view.SampleGridTwoFragment$1.onItemClick(SampleGridTwoFragment.java:119)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-18 13:38:24.940: E/WindowManager(585):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I saw so many questions in AsyncTask problem in SO, but none of that helps me. I need a help...

Comment: you must be doing ui operations in doInBackground(). Do the same in onPreExecute and onPostExecute.

Comment: @Raghunandan: So how will i have to use it in onPreExecute and onPostExecute?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Link should help you understand asynctask better

Comment: @Raghunandan: I studied it before, but i can't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `hh.initialize()`, you are already in the background thread and it is too late to create a `Handler`. In fact, your code is trying to do a lot of UI stuff from the background thread. You should separate out what actually needs to be done outside of the UI thread into a separate method and only invoke that method from `doInBackground` of your AsyncTask.

Comment: Then in my case how can i achieve it?

Comment: @AbdulRahman - To start with, I would define a constructor for `ActivityWeatherSetting` and move the creation of the `Handler` to the constructor. Then in `Task`, I would move the call to `new ActivityWeatherSetting()` from `doInBackground` to `onPreExecute` and save it in an instance variable. That will create the handler on the UI thread and should get rid of this particular exception. If you run into problems after that, post another question with the updated code. Good luck!

Comment: I created a constructor for the `ActivityWeatherSetting`, then i created the `Handler` in constructor, later i called `new ActivityWeatherSetting()` on `onPreExecute`, but still didn't get the solution, ProgressDialog is still loading.

Comment: @AbdulRahman - Are you still getting the same exception ("Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()")?

Comment: Not the same exception, but Progress Bar is loading on long time.

Comment: @AbdulRahman - It sounds like you have more problems with the code. I suggest that you start a new question where you paste in the code you now have and the details about the new exception. The progress bar is probably showing a long time because of the new exception. It's hard to tell without seeing the new code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19702/discussion-between-abdul-rahman-and-ted-hopp)